# Finding the values in Big Oh

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am going through the Asymptotic notations from [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0310-002/chapters/chapter-01.html). I am reading this `f(n) ≤ c g(n)`

For example, if f(n) = 2n + 2, We can satisfy it in any way as `f(n) is O (c.g(n))` by adjusting the value of `n` and `c`. Or is there any specific rule or formula for selecting the value of `c` and `n`. Will no always be 1?

Comment: It's in O of the highest degree of n, as everything else is insignificant at large values of n, so for this example it's O(n). C is any constant, n is the highest degree of n

Comment: so for 2n + 2 <= cn , my values `1 for c` and `1 for n`, can false the term, but if I select `3 as c` and `n=2` then this f(n) is O(c.g(n))

Comment: You are missing a constant from the definition. `f(n) <= cg(n)` doesn't have to hold for all `n`, but rather all `n >= n0` for some fixed `n0`. You get to pick `c` and `n0`.

Comment: Yes, but is there any formula for picking c and n0? or I can randomly put any value and satisfy the equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formula per se. You can find the formal definition here:

`f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.` ([big-O notation](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html)).

[image]

What I understood from your question is, you are not getting the essence of big-O notation. If your complexity is, for example, `O(n^2)`, then you can guarantee that there is some value of n (greater than k) after which `f(n)` in no case will exceed `c g(n)`.

Let's try to prove `f(n) = 2n + 2` is `O(n)`:

1. As it seems from the function itself, you cannot set the value of `c` equal to `2` as you want to find `f(n) ≤ c g(n)`. If you plug in `c = 2`, you have to find `k` such that `f(n) ≤ c g(n)` for `n ≥ k`. Clearly, there is no `n` for which `2n ≥ 2n + 2`. So, we move on to `c = 3`.
2. Now, let's find the value of `k`. So, we solve the equation `3n ≥ 2n + 2`. Solving it:

   `3n ≥ 2n + 2
   => 3n - 2n ≥ 2
   => n ≥ 2`

Therefore, for `c = 3`, we found value of `k = 2` (n ≥ k).

You must also understand, your function isn't just `O(n)`. It is also `O(n^2), O(n^3), O(n^4)` and so on. All because corresponding values of `c` and `k` exist for `g(n) = n^2`, `g(n) = n^3` and `g(n) = n^4`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. So the value of `c` is based on hit n trial? like we will keep checking 3 and then 4 and so on? and how we know it should not be `2`. I am sorry for very basic question

Comment: @AHF, you generally take a value of c which is just greater than the coefficient of the highest degree in the polynomial. For `f(n) = 2n + 2`, the coefficient of highest degree is 2, so you take `c = 2 + 1`. For another example, `f(n) = 5n^2 + 2n + 2`, the coefficient of highest degree is 5, so you take `c = 6`, where it is `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: What in case of polynomials ? like `5n^4 + 3n^3+ 2n^2=4n+1` ? if we take `c=6` then it will `5n^4 + 3n^3+ 2n^2=4n+1 = 6n^4` , but it will be wrong for 1 and 2 and 3 and so on

Comment: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci220s1t/lectures/lecturenotes/GG-lectures/BigOhexamples.pdf. You should see these lecture notes. The idea is like this:

Comment: Let's take your original polynomial:
`f(n) = 5n^4 + 3n^3 + 2n^2 - 4n - 1 ≤ c n^4`
`=> 5 + (3 / n) + (2 / n^2) + (4 / n^3) - (1 / n^4) ≤ c`-- (1)

For `n ≥ 1`, `5 + (3 / n) + (2 / n^2) + (4 / n^3) - (1 / n^4)` is less than or equal to `13`. 

(Putting `n = 1` in `5 + (3 / n) + (2 / n^2) + (4 / n^3) - (1 / n^4)`, you get `5 + 3 + 2 + 4 - 1 = 13`). 
Since we proved `5 + (3 / n) + (2 / n^2) + (4 / n^3) - (1 / n^4) ≤ 13` -- (2).

Comment: From equations (1) and (2), we have, `c = 13`. Did I clear you doubts? :)